# Instagram API - How to Subscribe to a specific User

Tags: java, web-applications, instagram-api

I am trying to use the Instagram-API to subscribe to a user so that when that user posts anything on Instagram, then my app will receive a POST. I have set up the app in the sandbox, defined the callback URIs, added my user to the Sandbox, then called the following url to register a subscription;

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&object=user&user_id=jonlees1234&aspect=media&verify_token=1234567890&callback_url=https://instagram.pulselive.com/SubscriptionCallback
```

The part of that URL that I am unclear about is the following;

&object=user&user_id=jonlees1234&aspect=media

I have a GET and POST method on my Callback Url so that when the SubscriptionValidation GET is called the hub.challenge is echoed. I have tested this and it works. However, the response I get from the above URL is as follows;

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

This indicates that all is working, but that there are no subscriptions when I run the list of subscriptions api call.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally I found the answer.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&object=user&id=3111490094&aspect=media&verify_token=THE_USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN&callback_url=http://instagram.pulselive.com/SubscriptionCallback
```

The KEY issue was that I was using the username and I SHOULD have been using the user id, as follows;

&object=user&id=1234567890&aspect=media

All working now.

Comment: This works?  The documentation says subscribing to user->media subscribes you to every post from *every user* who authenticates your app.  There is nothing about subscribing to a single user.